# Компиляция на C++ со статической библиотекой в конечном бинарнике

Tags: c++, openssl

В программе используется помимо стадартных vector, thread, iostream и прочего библиотека OpenSSL (openssl/evp.h и openssl/sha512.h). Компилирую проект так:

```
g++ main.cpp -lcrypto
```

Теперь, когда софтина готова к продакшену, встал вопрос: а как же ее собрать таким образом, чтобы конечному пользователю не пришлось докидывать к бинарнику нужные dll, т.е. чтобы получить на выходе полноценный исполняемый файл, пускай не 100КБ весом, зато самодостаточный :)

Желательно не использовать make, а сделать все линковки строкой в командной строке.

Comment: да в общем-то также, только линковать статическую библиотеку crypto

Comment: Зачем тогда брать `dll`, если нужна `lib`? Кстати, под Windows с `dll` частенько нужна и `lib`.

Comment: user7860670, немного бы подробнее ваш ответ, было бы совсем хорошо

Comment: а куда подробнее? соберите crypto в виде статической библиотеки, а не динамической, тогда приведенная команда слинкует со статической библиотекой...

Comment: @user7860670, например я заметил, что в директории с библиотеками (откуда линкую -lcrypto), есть файл libcrypto_static.lib, что меня обрадовало, однако статикой клеятся только файлы с расширением .a (OS Windows). Как мне собрать .lib -> .a, или как сразу задействовать libcrypto-static.lib? Буду премного благодарен

Comment: никак, дона собирать crypto в виде статической библиотеки ну или найдите готовый бинарик для вашей версии mingw